# Can't log into workbench

Tags: drools

I deployed kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.1.0.Final-jboss-as7.0.war into a JBoss 6.3 AS, and added an admin user in the application realm using the `add-user.sh` command. The login page of KIE Workbench can display, but when I click the login button, the following error occurs:

> BWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 - JBWEB000006: Invalid direct reference to
>   form login page
>
> JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report
>
> JBWEB000068: message JBWEB000006: Invalid direct reference to form
>   login page
>
> JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000120: The request sent by the client
>   was syntactically incorrect.
>
> JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4

I also deployed the Tomcat version, the login page failed to authenticate the user login with the following errors:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception type 
Exception report message 
Filter execution threw an exception description 
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. 
exception javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception 
root cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/jacc/PolicyContext 
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.source.JACCAuthenticationSource.getSubjectFrom‌​Container(JACCAuthenticationSource.java:155) 
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.source.JACCAuthenticationSource.loadRoles(JACC‌​AuthenticationSource.java:88) 
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.HttpAuthenticationManager.authenticate(HttpAut‌​henticationManager.java:178) 
org.uberfire.security.server.HttpSecurityManagerImpl.authenticate(HttpSecurityMa‌​nagerImpl.java:216) 
org.uberfire.security.server.UberFireSecurityFilter.authenticate(UberFireSecurit‌​yFilter.java:337) org.uberfire.security.server.UberFireSecurityFilter.doFilter(UberFireSecurityFil‌​ter.java:278) 
root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:17‌​20) 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:15‌​71) 
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.source.JACCAuthenticationSource.getSubjectFrom‌​Container(JACCAuthenticationSource.java:155)
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.source.JACCAuthenticationSource.loadRoles(JACC‌​AuthenticationSource.java:88) 
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.HttpAuthenticationManager.authenticate(HttpAut‌​henticationManager.java:178) 
org.uberfire.security.server.HttpSecurityManagerImpl.authenticate(HttpSecurityMa‌​nagerImpl.java:216) 
org.uberfire.security.server.UberFireSecurityFilter.authenticate(UberFireSecurit‌​yFilter.java:337) 
org.uberfire.security.server.UberFireSecurityFilter.doFilter(UberFireSecurityFil‌​ter.java:278)
```

Comment: I also deployed the tomcat version, the login page failed to authenticate user login with the following errors:

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception

type Exception report

message Filter execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
root cause

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/jacc/PolicyContext
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.source.JACCAuthenticationSource.getSubjectFromContainer(JACCAuthenticationSource.java:155)
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.source.JACCAuthenticationSource.loadRoles(JACCAuthenticationSource.java:88)
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.HttpAuthenticationManager.authenticate(HttpAuthenticationManager.java:178)
org.uberfire.security.server.HttpSecurityManagerImpl.authenticate(HttpSecurityManagerImpl.java:216)

Comment: org.uberfire.security.server.UberFireSecurityFilter.authenticate(UberFireSecurityFilter.java:337)
org.uberfire.security.server.UberFireSecurityFilter.doFilter(UberFireSecurityFilter.java:278)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.source.JACCAuthenticationSource.getSubjectFromContainer(JACCAuthenticationSource.java:155)

Comment: org.uberfire.security.server.auth.source.JACCAuthenticationSource.loadRoles(JACCAuthenticationSource.java:88)
org.uberfire.security.server.auth.HttpAuthenticationManager.authenticate(HttpAuthenticationManager.java:178)
org.uberfire.security.server.HttpSecurityManagerImpl.authenticate(HttpSecurityManagerImpl.java:216)
org.uberfire.security.server.UberFireSecurityFilter.authenticate(UberFireSecurityFilter.java:337)
org.uberfire.security.server.UberFireSecurityFilter.doFilter(UberFireSecurityFilter.java:278)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 log

Comment: Please do not use comments to add information to you question. You can edit the question to do that.

Comment: Putting jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar into $TOMCAT_HOME/lib getting this problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have not download the KIE Execution Server, please download this: https://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/kie-server-distribution-6.5.0.Final.zip. Put it in the tomcat webapps folder, and config the setenv.sh like this:

> CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dbtm.root=$CATALINA_HOME
>   -Dorg.jbpm.cdi.bm=java:comp/env/BeanManager -Dbitronix.tm.configuration=$CATALINA_HOME/conf/btm-config.properties -Djbpm.tsr.jndi.lookup=java:comp/env/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry
>   -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/kie-drools-web/WEB-INF/classes/login.config
>   -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.ds=java:comp/env/jdbc/jbpm -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.tm=org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform
>   -Dorg.kie.server.id=tomcat-kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server-6.5.0.Final-webc/services/rest/server
>   -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-web/rest/controller
>   -Dorg.kie.server.user=tomcat -Dorg.kie.server.pwd=tomcat -Dorg.kie.server.controller.user=tomcat -Dorg.kie.server.controller.pwd=tomcat"